# Lightning Data Service, insert new record then clear and insert another

Tags: lightning, lightning-data-service

I am trying to use Lightning Data Service, force:recordData, with a component to insert new records. It successfully inserts one but then I want to clear the text and be able to insert another. Is LDS capable of this ? When I insert the second record it just uses the same ID as the first one and changes the fields to what should be the second record.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
<aura:attribute name="newQuestion" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="newQuestionError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleQuestion" type="Object"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="questionCreator"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{! v.newQuestion }"
                  targetError="{! v.newQuestionError }"
                  targetFields="{! v.simpleQuestion }"/>

<lightning:card title="Add a Question" class="slds-p-horizontal_medium">

    <div class="slds-form_stacked slds-p-top_medium slds-p-bottom_medium" style="color: black; width: 600px;">
        <lightning:textarea name="question" class="" value="{! v.simpleQuestion.body__c }" label="Question" 
                            maxlength="500" required="true"/>
        <lightning:textarea name="answer" class="" value="{! v.simpleQuestion.answer__c }" label="Answer"
                            maxlength="500" required="true"/>
        <lightning:input name="category" class="" label="Category" value="{! v.simpleQuestion.Category__c }"/>        

       <div class="slds-p-top_medium">
            <button class="slds-button" onclick="{! c.createQuestion }">
              <lightning:icon iconName="action:new" size="small" alternativeText="Do something" />
            </button>
       </div>

    </div>

</lightning:card>
```

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("questionCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Question__c", null, false, 
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newQuestion");
            var error = component.get("v.newQuestionError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
        })
    );
},

createQuestion : function(component, event, helper) {
    //submit that record
    component.find("questionCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult){
        if(saveResult.state == "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state == "DRAFT"){
            var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            resultsToast.setParams({
                "title":"Question Saved",
                "message":"You added a new Question to the Question Bank"   
            });

            resultsToast.fire();

        } else if(saveResult.state =="ERROR"){
            var errorToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            errorToast.setParams({
                "title":"Error",
                "message":"This question wasn't added, check the log"
            });

            console.log('Problem saving: '+JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));

            errorToast.fire();
        } 
    });

    //Load a new record

     component.find("questionCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Question__c", null, false, 
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newQuestion");
            var error = component.get("v.newQuestionError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.sobjectType);
        })
    );

},
```

I'm thinking that I could use javascript to set the simpleQuestion attribute to a new question but I thought that was what `getNewRecord` was supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getNewRecord simply loads a record with default values based on record type. To actually create a new record, remember to clear out the recordId attribute:

```
component.find("questionCreator").set("v.recordId", null);
```

Comment: The thing is I don't have that 'recordId' attribute, I don't implement 'force:hasRecordId',  this page isn't supposed to be in a 'record context' I am only wanting to use the data service to insert new records. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I see what you mean, the force:recordData has is how you access the newly created record. Thanks!